# Do the notations ⅃⅃⅃ ___ LLL mean anything?

Tags: notation

[image]

There are some notations above the characters:

> ⅃⅃⅃ ___ LLL
>
> 大      人    国

Do these notations mean anything?

Comment: Looks like shadows from three raised blocks above each character. Directions of light sources are funny though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a more clear picture. I think they are not letters or characters. They are only decoration for the "大人国". The reason is the angle of view of your picture.You can see your picture carefully again.

[image]